# VB.net application is moving word images and tables locations on the page

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code to open a word document in vb.net then save it with a different filename

```
Dim oWord As New word.Application
Dim oDoc As word.Document
oWord.Visible = False

oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("c:\integra-billing\integra-invoice-summary.docx", False, True)

/// some code here to add/change content in the document ///

filename = "c:\integra-billing\detail\VoIP" + " -" + customer_sequence + ".doc"
oDoc_detail.SaveAs(FileName:=filename, FileFormat:=word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument97)
oWord_detail.Documents.Close(word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
oWord_detail.Quit()
oWord_detail = Nothing
```

Once it has saved the file, its moving my table and images down the page and not in the correct place.

How can i stop it from change the location/positions of things.

Comment: Change your default printer.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe caused because of Changing the file format from `docx` to `doc` to prevent this change :

```
filename = "c:\integra-billing\detail\VoIP" + " -" + customer_sequence + ".docx"
oDoc_detail.SaveAs(FileName:=filename, FileFormat:=word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument)
```

Comment: I have tried that, but its still doing the same thing